# matplotlib with pgf, error: dimension too large

Tags: python, matplotlib, pgf

In using the `pgf` backend of `matplotlib`, I sometimes see an error like this:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \advance 
l.69 ...o{\pgfqpoint{-11.400000in}{-235.382893in}}
```

This is from the LaTeX processing step, it will happen if I ask matplotlib for a png, or when processing a document with the pgf file embedded. It happens when I set axes limits that are very narrow compared to the data limits. So I assume that pgf receives and tries to process or plot the whole data set, and some of the points that are outside the intended visible range are also outside pgf's internal size limit.

MWE:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5,5)
y = 100*np.exp(x)

plt.xlim((-0.1,0.1))
plt.ylim((99,101))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.savefig('exp.png')
```

My question: **is there some way that I can have matplotlib feed pgf a limited set of data?** Or is there some other solution to this? I could truncate the data I feed into the pyplot command according to my desired limits, but I'm hoping matplotlib has an internal solution to save me from a lot of case-by-case fidgeting. (There's also a case when I'm adding spline patches to the axes, I don't know how to cut off part of the curve.)

I've looked in some of the documentation and saw `get_clip_on()` and `get_clip_box()` of `Line2D`, but after any regular plot command the former method returns True anyway and the latter returns some `TransformedBbox` specification, presumably something representing the axes themselves.

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it's not reproducible in `matplotlib v3.4.2`

Comment: Not reproducible in `3.4.1` either. Voted to close also.

Answer (score -2):

**Try This Code**

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-5, 5)
y = 100 * np.exp(x)

x_limit = (-0.1, 0.1)
y_limit = (99, 101)

# Filter data based on visible range
visible_data = (x_limit[0] <= x) & (x <= x_limit[1]) & (y_limit[0] <= y) & (y <= y_limit[1])

plt.xlim(x_limit)
plt.ylim(y_limit)

plt.plot(x[visible_data], y[visible_data])
plt.savefig('exp.png')
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.